# Return value from override function

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm not sure what I'm looking to do is even possible.  If it is, it's new to me.

here's a basic outline of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class MyClass : SomeInterface {

    fun makeSomethingHappen() {
        methodInInterfaceThatReturnsValueBelow()
    }

    override fun iDidSomething(result: Value) {
        //give this value back to the original caller of makeSomethingHappen()
    }

    override fun iDidSomethingElse(result: Value) {
        //give this value back to the original caller of makeSomethingHappen()
    }

    override fun onFailure(result: Value) {
        //give this value back to the original caller of makeSomethingHappen()
    }
}
```

Explanation:

We're using a required SDK that has about 15 overrides.  I call into this class to call a function in the SDK.  That function is going to call one of the override functions when it's done.

Is there a way (live data, flows, anything) to have whoever called makeSomethingHappen() receive the value from any of the override methods?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--you want to return something from `makeSomethingHappen`?

Comment: @davenewton no, I want to return something from one of the override funs to whatever called `makeSomethingHappen`

Comment: You want to call `makeSomethingHappen` and have the value received by the caller come from a different method?

Comment: Basically.  I know I can do it would a broadcast receiver (call the method, override method sends broadcast that calling class listens too), was just seeing if there was something cleaner

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of reactive programming. You wait for an event that a producer/observable emits, it's like when you declare a click listener on a button.

You can't return the value in `makeSomethingHappen()`, but you can create a listener and the observer implements that listener to get the value.

```
typealias MyListener = (Value) -> Unit

class MyClass : SomeInterface {

    private var _listeners: List<MyListener> = mutableListOf()

    fun addListener(listener: MyListener) {
        _listeners.add(listener)
    }

    fun makeSomethingHappen() {
        methodInInterfaceThatReturnsValueBelow()
    }

    override fun iDidSomething(result: Value) {
        // Send result Value to the listener implementations
        _listeners.forEach { it.invoke(result) }
    }

    override fun iDidSomethingElse(result: Value) {
        // Send result Value to the listener implementations
        _listeners.forEach { it.invoke(result) }
    }

    override fun onFailure(result: Value) {
        // Send result Value to the listener implementations
        _listeners.forEach { it.invoke(result) }
    }
}
```

The you can get the result implementing `MyListener`

```
val myClass = MyClass()
myClass.makeSomethingHappen { value ->
    // Here you have the value and you can do whatever
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: +1.  This is good.  Expanding on this just a bit:  What if it's a singleton class with multiple possible listeners?

Comment: If you want to have multiple subscribers instead of having an unique listener, you will need a list of listeners, and to invoke the listeners you would do: `_listeners.forEach { it.invoke(value) }`. If this case is very common on your project there are other options, you can use a reactive framework like [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) where you can do this stuff in a better and sophisticated way

Comment: I just updated the response to work with multiple listeners