# How can I return a list from within an override function?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following block of Kotlin code:

```
private fun clientInitialization(client: AsyncHttpClient, index: Int, movieAttributes: List<String>) {
        var movieInfoList = mutableListOf<String>()
        client["https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=xxxxxx", object : JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int,headers: Headers,json: JsonHttpResponseHandler.JSON) {
                var arrayLength = json.jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").length()

                if (index < arrayLength){
                    for (item in movieAttributes){
                        var currentAttribute = json.jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(index).getString(item)
                        movieInfoList.add(currentAttribute)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int,headers: Headers?,errorResponse: String,throwable: Throwable?) {
                Log.d("Pic error", errorResponse)
            }

        }]
    }
```

I am trying to return that movieInfoList from within the override on succes function. As a newbie to Kotlin, I really don't know how I can best navigate this or any other ways I can get past this.I have tried adding listeners as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59778256/return-value-from-override-function) answer but I couldn't get that to work

######################################

I tried adding listeners, but that also failed

Comment: Possible duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o?r=Saves_AllUserSaves Lots of good info about this situation there. I think the answer by Tyler V will be most helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return "movieInfoList" after adding data in `onSuccess`? So it is impossible because `clientInitialization` is returned immediately after invoking `client["https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=xxxxxx"`. Your callback is asynchronous.
In this case, you can try to use [Kotlin suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html)

```
private suspend fun clientInitialization(client: AsyncHttpClient, index: Int, movieAttributes: List<String>) : List<String> {
return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cancelable -> 
    val callback = object : JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int,headers: Headers,json: JsonHttpResponseHandler.JSON) {
            var arrayLength = json.jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").length()
            val movieInfoList = mutableListOf<String>()
            if (index < arrayLength){
                for (item in movieAttributes){
                    var currentAttribute = json.jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(index).getString(item)
                    movieInfoList.add(currentAttribute)
                }
            }
            cancelable.resume(movieInfoList)
        }

        override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int,headers: Headers?,errorResponse: String,throwable: Throwable?) {
            Log.d("Pic error", errorResponse)
            cancelable.resume(emptyList())
        }
    }
    client["https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=xxxxxx", callback]
    cancelable.invokeOnCancellation { 
        //TODO cancel your client's call
    }
}
```

}